# printf dynamic length/size

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a dynamic printf size for a lcd but it outputs only f=  what do i do wrong?

```
sprintf(buffer, "f=%.2f",  (d = d + 0.01)); <-- works but not dynamic 

sprintf(buffer, "f=%.*f", 2 , (d = d + 0.01));  <-- Does not any give warning

lcd_puts(buffer);


_delay_ms(100);
```

Comment: it looks correct and works here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you need this:

```
char format[10];
int len1 = 5, len2 = 2;
sprintf(format, "f=%%%d.%df", len1, len2);
sprintf(buffer, format , (d = d + 0.01));
```